# Error con iterator en Java Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, iteradores

Estoy usando este código para recorrer una lista de trabajadores que puede contener objetos de tres clases: *Mecánico, Comercial y Jefe*.

Para otra lista que tengo de solo clientes uso **for:each**, pero solo contiene objetos de una misma *clase Clientes*. Uso el iterator porque hasta donde yo sé es la única forma de recorrer la lista entera si contiene objetos de diferentes clases.

```
Iterator <Trabajador> miIterador = trabajadores.iterator();

System.out.println("\nIntroduzca el DNI de la persona que desea consultar:");
entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
dni = entrada.nextLine();

while(miIterador.hasNext()) {
    if(miIterador.next().getDni().compareToIgnoreCase(dni)==0) {
        encontrado=1;
        System.out.println(miIterador.next().toString());
    }
}

if(encontrado==0) {
    System.out.println("\nCliente no encontrado.");
}
```

El problema es que me salta el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
>           at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextNode(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedKeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
>           at taller.Main.main(Main.java:103)

Pero esto solo ocurre cuando se encuentra en el último objeto, por ejemplo:

Si yo introduzco manualmente a tres trabajadores con dni 1, 2 y 3 respectivamente, puedo buscar e imprimir el 1 y 2 sin problema, pero el 3 me da ese error. He pensado en crear un objeto "invisible" automaticamente e ir moviéndolo cada vez que se da de alta un nuevo trabajador para que los creados por el usuario nunca sean los últimos y nunca de error al consultarlos, *pero creo que probablamente estaré teniendo algún error de códugo que desconozco y no es necesario liarlo tanto*.

Gracias de antemano!!

Comment: Eso te pasa porque cada vez que ejecutas `next()` te retorna el siguiente. Primero ejecutas `next` para obtener y comparar el DNI y luego ejecutas `next()` otra vez para imprimir, y este es el siguiente elemento del usado para comparar el DNI, con lo que cuando llegas al último, el segundo `next` te da el error. Guarda el retorno del primer `next()`, que será un objeto `Trabajador`, y usa el objeto para imprimir,  no ejecutes otra vez `next()`.

Comment: Cierto, no me había fijado, muchas gracias!!

Comment: @SuperG280 Te animo a poner ese comentario como respuesta

Comment: @SuperG280 ¿puedo poner entonces miIterador.toString() directamente para imprimir los datos? O tengo que guardar miIterador.next() en algun objeto y luego imprimir los datos del mismo?

Comment: Solo añadir que iterator no es la única forma de recorrer una lista que contenga objetos de clases diferentes. Se puede hacer perfectamente con un bucle for normal: `for (Trabajador trabajador: trabajadores) { ... }`

Comment: En realidad el `for ( : )` es azúcar sintáctico que internamente usa un iterador

Comment: @PabloLozano no sabía que internamente usaba un iterador. ¿También es así para un bucle `for (;;)`? Corrígeme si me equivoco, pero entiendo que si se hace así no se utilizarían iteradores ni de forma explícita ni implícita:  `for (int i = 0; i < trabajadores.size(); i++) { Trabajador trabajador = trabajadores.get(i); }`

Comment: No, sólo para el *enhanced for*: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433282/how-is-javas-for-loop-code-generated-by-the-compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para aclarar y que quede reflejado para la posteridad, escribiré la respuesta completa.

El problema está en que cada vez que ejecutas `next()` en un iterador, te retorna el siguiente elemento y en tu caso estás ejecutando `next()` dos veces en cada iteración del bucle.

El código quedaría así:

```
Iterator <Trabajador> miIterador = trabajadores.iterator();

System.out.println("\nIntroduzca el DNI de la persona que desea consultar:");
entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
dni = entrada.nextLine();

while(miIterador.hasNext()) {
    Trabajador trabajador = miIterator.next();
    if(trabajador.getDni().compareToIgnoreCase(dni)==0) {
        encontrado=1;
        System.out.println(trabajador.toString());
    }
}

if(encontrado==0) {
    System.out.println("\nCliente no encontrado.");
}
```